# how can you tell if a kitten will have short or long hair?

Tags: cats, pet-selection

I am getting a kitten from from a women, the momma cat and her kittens were dropped off at her house. They're not ready yet so I've only seen them in pictures. She estimated that they are about 4-5 weeks old because they have started eating a little wet food. The one that I am getting looks a lot fluffier than it's siblings so I was curious as to if it will have long or short hair? I figured it could be possible for one or more of the kittens to have long hair because no one knows who the farther is. I asked but she doesn't know/isn't sure. I was just wondering if anyone on here could tell? How or when could you tell? Pictures of the kitten and one of its siblings below

[image: kitten that I'm getting]
[image: Sibling of Kitten]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you tell if a kitten will have long or short hair?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5952/how-can-you-tell-if-a-kitten-will-have-long-or-short-hair)

Answer (score 1):

Your kitten looks to be medium to long-haired to me.Pretty fluffy. I have medium-haired cat who I rescued at 3 weeks old and his coat surprised me when it came in so I'm leaning to long-haired for your little one.

The longer hair hasn't been an issue and he likes being brushed. I started early to get him accustomed to being handled and brushed and do recommend it.

[image: Keirnan 3 weeks old][image: A recent pic]

Answer (score 1):

I think your kitten isn't a short-hair cat because of its **dense** and long-hair coat. If the mother or/and father of it has/have long hair, the possibility is higher. Also, some kittens have the medium-long but **thin** hair that would shed gradually since the fourth month. After that, their real coat-short hair- will appear soon. 
I also have a long-hair cat, I adopted him when he was five months old. At that time, he already had a white and dense and long fur. However, I adopted another short-hair kitten (about 4 weeks). His hair was shorter and thinner than your kitten when I first saw him. After 3 months, I can certify he is a real short-hair cat!
[image: This is the first cat I mentioned above.]

[image]