# My kitten has thick fur with shaggy longer hair all over, except on his head. Will he end up with medium fur?

Tags: cats

My kitten is a stray, I think 8 to 9 weeks old, so I don't know how long the fur on his parents were.

His fur feels thick under with shaggy long hairs on top. Can anyone estimate what kind of fur he will end up with?

[image]

Comment: Related: [How can you tell if a kitten will have long or short hair?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5952/how-can-you-tell-if-a-kitten-will-have-long-or-short-hair)

Comment: Based on the linked question, it may be helpful to post pictures of the cats paws

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If he will be a medium hair cat](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17719/if-he-will-be-a-medium-hair-cat)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you tell if a kitten will have long or short hair?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5952/how-can-you-tell-if-a-kitten-will-have-long-or-short-hair)