# If he will be a medium hair cat

Tags: cats

[image][image] wondering if he will be medium hair cat when he is older.

Comment: Hard to tell honestly, some times the coat doesn't grow out until later other times it shows early.  Best bet is to get a vet's opinion.  In terms of my non expertise experience, both of my kittens looked like the top cat and turned out to be medium haired.

Comment: hmmm it appears you asked this question twice ><

Comment: Yes I did I wanted to show better picture of him . I am sorry

Comment: no worries!  also welcome to Pets Stack Exchange!  for future reference, you can always edit your question should you have the desire to change pictures or add information you previously left out :)

Comment: Thank you ;) I had a kitten a long time ago and right from the start I could tell she was short hair.him he got me thinking.

Comment: Yes, it is hard to tell.  Mine are brother and sister from the same litter.  Look almost exactly like your first picture (same coat patterns and colors too), I got them when they were 4 weeks old (long story lol) and now that they are a year and a couple months they are mostly fully grown.  My male is fairly fluffy and has a nice maine going while my female is definitely a short haired (though she does have fairly long and fluffy chest hair).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it'll probably grow to be a medium haired cat, doesn't need a vet to know that.